# Asset image as a Card background with text on top in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using a Card widget in flutter to display text. I want to use an asset image as the background/texture for the card, and display text on top. I'm having trouble figuring out how to layer the widgets properly. Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
    Card(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("images/image.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text("YOUR TEXT"),
      ),
    ),
```